# Strange error when just hovering over datagrid

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGrid that is located on a TabPage of a TabControl. I load that DataGrid with an anonymous List that I make from two other tables. Everything loads find, but when I select the tab to see the DataGrid, I get this strange error message that I can not begin to understand. Here is the code:

```
Using context = New iTracContext
    Dim RecordList As New List(Of TrainingRecord)
    Dim AnonymousList As New List(Of Object)

    RecordList = context.TrainingRecords.Include("TrainingReference").Include("employee").Where(Function(e) e.due_date < Date.Today And e.completed = 0).ToList
    For Each item In RecordList
        Dim fLink As New FileLink
        fLink = context.FileLinks.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.SourceID = item.TrainingReference.id And f.LinkType = "training")
        If Not fLink Is Nothing Then
            AnonymousList.Add(New With {item.Employee.FirstName, item.Employee.LastName, item.Employee.JobTitle, item.due_date, fLink.Description})
        Else
            AnonymousList.Add(New With {item.Employee.FirstName, item.Employee.LastName, item.Employee.JobTitle, item.due_date})
        End If
    Next

    Return AnonymousList
End Using
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Exception message for property `FirstName` says: _Object does not match target type_ - Check what column type is configured for the column where `FirstName` property is bounded and does type of FirstName and expected type are similar

Comment: Where is this code running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem (newbie!), my code had a if function that inserted 5 columns under one condition and it inserted only 4 columns under the other condition. DUH!
All is good now! Thanks for the input!